# Input a dataset into Vowpalwabbit

Tags: vowpalwabbit

If I have data set in tsv format on my desktop, How can I give it as input into vowpal I tried vw -d/Desktop/Boston.tsv it cannot the read the file. I am new to vowpal and shell scripting. please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You should familiarize yourself with VW [input format](https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Input-format).

Then you can take a look on [set of bash commands](https://www.kaggle.com/c/criteo-display-ad-challenge/forums/t/9583/beat-the-benchmark-with-vowpal-wabbit/53060#post53060) used by one of kagglers (xbsd). It's for kaggle's contest specific dataset which was in csv. I believe you can adapt it for tsv (it's the tab separated csv, isn't it?) by changing `perl -wnlaF','` to `perl -wnlaF'\t'`. And you should adjust field indexes in `$F[]` for your specific dataset.

Then you can use it as `vw -d Boston.vw` or just `vw Boston.vw`

Comment: Yes, and importantly: OP should say which field in the `.tsv` file is the target feature (aka 'label'). In `vw` format, the label comes first, right at the beginning of each line so field reordering may be needed.